# Majorana Dirac equation in 1+1 dimensions

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

While working out the continuum limit of the transverse field Ising model in the Majorana representation (see, for example, either Fradkin's *[Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521764440)* or Shankar's *[Quantum Field Theory and Condensed Matter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521592100)*), I've arrived at a continuum equation of motion for the two-component Majorana field $\chi(x)$ of the form
$$
i \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t} = -i \sigma^x \partial_x \chi + m \sigma^y \chi.
$$
This equation makes perfect sense to me as the non-covariant form a 1+1 dimensional Dirac equation: I would call $\sigma^x = \alpha$ and $\sigma^y = \beta$.

However, in defining the gamma matrices to obtain the covariant expression, I see two different choices being used in the literature -- for example, Shankar takes the first approach on page 153 in chapter 9, while Fradkin takes the second choice on page 120 in chapter 5. One choice is to define $\gamma^0 = \sigma^y$ and $\gamma^1 = \sigma^y \sigma^x = -i\sigma^z$, from which we see after multiplying through by $\sigma^y$ that $\chi$ satisfies the usual Dirac equation:
$$
(i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - m) \chi = 0.
$$
The other choice is to define $\gamma^0 = -\sigma^z$ and $\gamma^1 = -\sigma^z \sigma^x = -i \sigma^y$, which gives a mass term which appears somewhat unusual to me:
$$
(i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} -i m \sigma^x)\chi = 0.
$$
Clearly, these two forms are completely equivalent. However, the latter seems quite cosmetically weird to me. After some googling, I've seen both forms above appear with relatively similar frequencies.

Here's my question: how should I interpret the strange mass term $i m \sigma^x$? Is there any particular reason I might want to write the equation in one form or the other? Or is the second method just a strange way of writing the Dirac equation in 1+1 dimensions? Furthermore, is this related to some peculiarity of 1+1 dimensions, or is it a more general feature?

Comment: I have not looked at your references yet, but isn't this just the Majorana mass term that appears from the construction of a right-handed Weyl spinor  $\chi_R=i\sigma^{x}\chi_L^*$ which then when re-writing the Dirac equation in terms of $\chi_L$, you get your equation with this massive Majorana term $im\sigma^x$?

Comment: I don't know -- I'm not much of a high energy person, so I don't have a ton of experience with the Dirac equation beyond the basics. If you can provide a reference, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is in pretty much in any book on intermediate to advanced QFT. If I recall, Zee's book _Quantum field theory in a nutshell_ is pretty comprehensive in these topics. I may (if I have time) write a more involved answer later, if no one beats me to it.

Comment: you have to be really carefull with fradkin's book it is full of typos and sign mistakes. so I would use that book only for concepts and not take the calculations too seriously.

Comment: I completely agree -- in fact, even though he is full of lots of great insights, some of the particular technical statements he makes are even just plain wrong! Nevertheless, this was a calculation I performed quite carefully, and corroborated with multiple different sources to check, which is where I found the discrepancy.